# Show li elements based on data attribute range

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter

I have HTML like:

```
<ul>
<li data-time="450">...</li>
<li data-time="430">...</li>
<li data-time="550">...</li>
<li data-time="750">...</li>
<li data-time="80">...</li>
<li data-time="170">...</li>
</ul>
```

and I have slider which gives me min and max values.
etc.

```
min = 200;
max = 400;
```

How I can filter (show only) elements where date-time values are between 200 and 400 using jquery?

I tried:

```
     $( "#slider-range" ).on( "slidechange", function( event, ui ) {
        console.log(ui.values);
$('li').hide();
        min = ui.values[0];
        max = ui.values[1];
        //dont know to show only <li> elements between min and max
    } );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.each()` to iterate the items. Extract the `data-time` (using `.data()` as getter automatically converts to number), for each element apply display `none` or `block` if it's out/in bounds.

```js
var min = 200;
var max = 500;

$( "li" ).each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var time = $this.data('time');
  
  $this.css('display', (time < min || time > max) ? 'none' : 'block');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li data-time="450">450</li>
  <li data-time="430">430</li>
  <li data-time="550">550</li>
  <li data-time="750">750</li>
  <li data-time="80">80</li>
  <li data-time="170">170</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Also works without the `+` when getting the time as `data()` automatically converts the value to a number.

Answer (score 0):

Hey try this snippet.

```
$( "#slider-range" ).on( "slidechange", function( event, ui ) {
    console.log(ui.values);

    // hide all
    $('li').hide();

    // loop between min and max and select and show the ones the exist
    min = ui.values[0];
    max = ui.values[1];
    for(var value=min;value<=max;value++) {
        var liElement = $("li[data-time='"+ value +"']");
        if(liElement) {
            liElement.show();
        }
    }
});
```